# Connect domain controller Windows Server 2003 to another one on Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, domain-controller, rpc

In Active directory, when I try to connect to another domain controller, after adding that  domain controller and press ok, a message appears to me:

`The following domain controller could not be contacted, the RPC server is unavailable`

How can I fix this problem.

Comment: If you want good quality help, you may need to improve your question a little. What have you tried so far? Can you ping one server from the other? Can you map a drive? Is the time + timezone correct on both of them (have you CHECKED, not assumed?). Are there any errors in the event log?

Comment: How have you added the domain controller? To what have you added it? How are you trying to connect to it?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with others that your questions is definitely not clear enough; anyway, since I've been fighting with a similar issue for all yesterday, I feel compelled to answer.

This can depend on a lot of things:

- Can the two computers actually talk to each other? Check with ping, mapping a network share, etc.
- Are they on the same subnet or on different ones? If they are on different ones, is there a firewall in the middle?
- Is the first domain controller (and the domain as a whole) operating correctly? Can you f.e. succesfully log on to domain computers, browse AD, etc.? You can perform a full check on them with DCDIAG.
- Is DNS consfigured correctly on the new DC? Does it use as its DNS servers the domain's already existing domain controllers, and *only them* (no external DNSs please!)?
- Is the tyme sync ok between the new DC and the current ones?
- Is the new DC already a domain member? If not, can you try joining it to the domain and then performing the DCPROMO after this is done (and logged in as a domain admin)?
- Related to the preceeding item: how are you logging in to the domain? I've been getting *exactly that error* because I was running DCPROMO with a local Administrator on the new DC, so I had to specify domain credentials for the promotion... and someone had filled the "domain" field with the domain's FQDN instead of the NetBIOS name. Everything was working perfectly, but I kept getting that "RPC server is unavailable" (quite misleading, BTW).

Comment: Not sure if it helped the OP, but your last bullet (NETBIOS vs. FQDN) helped me out. I'm still not sure why I can't Change Domain Controller using FQDN, but at least I can work around it with NETBIOS name instead. Thanks!